# Two values forced in one argument in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, closures

I'm a graphic designer who is self-studying front-end web development. I finished reading all about HTML and CSS. Now I'm reading about JavaScript, particularly a book called Eloquent JavaScript by Marijn Haverbeke (2011). On the topic of function closures he gives this example without much explanation:

```
function makeAdder(amount) {
    return function(number) {
        return number + amount;
    };
}

var addTwo = makeAdder(2);
addTwo(3);
-> 5
```

What I don't understand here is how the variable `number` is given a value, when it is inside an unnamed function `function(number)` inside the body of the function `makeAdder()`. The `makeAdder()` function accepts only one argument `amount`. This is given a value "2" in `makeAdder(2)`, is a variable definition of `addTwo`.

But then the variable `addTwo` is executed afterwards as if it were a function and given a different value of 3. Now whats really strange about this is how the value of 3 given to the `addTwo` function somehow ended up being used in the nested function body `number + amount` for the variable `number`, adding it with the value of amount (2), and finally ending with a final value of 5.

Comment: Basically when `makeAdder(2)` is called it just return a new function, that function know the value of _amount_ (set to 2). Then the new created function is called with 3 as param. At this point `addTwo` can sum _number + amount_ (3 + 2).  
If you call `makeAdder()`without parameter then when you try `addTwo(3)` it will return `NaN` because `addTwo` has _amount_ with `undefined` value (_3_ + _undefined_ = _NaN_).

Answer (score 0):

[3 ways to define a javascript class](http://phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class)

[Javascript.Info class](https://javascript.info/class)

When you call makeAdder,  it actually takes value of `amount`, places it into amount variable, and **returns a function**. It has not evaluated the inner returned function yet.

Then, when you call addTwo, it passes your parameter `number` to the inner function, then evalutes inner function and returns a response.

> Adding console.log statements in your code makes the sequence of assignment and call execution clear.
>   When you call the outer function, that literally behaves like creating an object of makeAdder.
>
> I am calling it a class because classes are created in javascript through function keywords, IIFE and more. When you create an object of makeAdder class, you assigned a member variable amount a value of 2.
>
> Since this variable remains inside object of class, and returns the function inside the scope of object of makeAdder, it is available to returned function. When you evaluate the returned function, value of the member variable .is available to the inner function. When inner function is evaluated, it takes value of member variable amount from the object of the class, and number from the parameter passed into it. Sums it up and returns result.

```js
function makeAdder(amount) {
console.log("value assigned to amount is " + amount);
  return function(number) {
   console.log("value assigned to number is " + number);
   return number + amount;
    };
   }

var addTwo = makeAdder(2);
console.log("value assigned to amount, now calling inner function");
console.log(addTwo(3));
```

**UPDATE BELOW:**

I changed your function to a somewhat class-compatible structure below.

1. When value of 2 is passed to amount, the outer function is evaluated (new object of class is created), a value of 2 is set for member variable this.amt from the value of amount provided by you (=2).
2. Another function is defined inside this object. It is named  as val, another function. It is just definition yet, not evaluation.
3. I return val as a function from the object of the class. So, a function is returned from the object, and its member variable this.amt has a value already.
4. I call the this.val function twice below. See the syntax. Why can I call it directly with a parameter? Because it returns a function ready to be evaluated.

   Calling the function with amount = 2, number = 5, 
   and then with amount = 8, number = 5

```js
var a = function(amount) {
      console.log("value assigned to amount is " + amount);
    
      this.amt = amount; 

      this.value = function(number) {
        console.log("value assigned to number is " + number);
        return number + amt;
      };
    
      return this.value;
   }
   

console.log(a(2)(5));
x = a(8);
console.log(x(5));
```

**SEE A EVEN CLEARER SNIPPET BELOW**
1. ax is defined as a function. It is intended to be used as class.

2. It has a member variable `amount` and a function `val` which ultimately calculates the sum of `number` and `amount` and returns the total.
3. A `new` object of ax is created and assigned to b. It initializes with default values.
4. Set the value of amount variable as 7.
5. Call the val function with number parameter as 8.
6. Get the result 15.

```js
    var ax = function() {
          
          this.amount = 0;
          
          this.val = function(number) 
          {
             console.log("value assigned to number is " + number);
             return number + this.amount;
          }
          
       }
       
    var b = new ax();
    b.amount=7;
    console.log(b.val(8));
```

**LAST SNIPPET**

1. ax defines a function. When you create a new object, pass a variable to it.
2. This assigns a value to this.amount inside the object of class, and returns nothing.
3. You can call another function which is inside this object now, by passing one parameter and using another from a member variable amount of the object.
4. You get the result.

```js
   var ax = function(amt) {
          
          this.amount = amt;
          
          this.val = function(number) 
          {
             console.log("value assigned to number is " + number);
             return number + this.amount;
          }
          
       }
       
    var b = new ax(6);
    console.log(b.val(8));
```

Answer (score 0):

This works because of something called **scoping**: an argument in a function is scoped inside the function, which means it's available throughout the entire function to use (similar to a variable declaration, which you can reuse throughout your entire codebase).

What this essentially means is that the argument `amount` is available inside the entire function, even inside the new function.

You can think about functions like this:

```
function foo(n) {
    return n + 2;
}

console.log(foo(5));

// What you have done is basically equivalent to this function:

function foo() {
    var n = 5;
    return n + 2;
}
```

When you call a function, it's like placing  a variable inside the function, and then executing it. Of course, this will log `7` to the console.

Now we can apply this to `makeAdder`:

```
function makeAdder(amount) {
  return function(number) {
    return number + amount;
  };
}

var addTwo = makeAdder(2);

// Turns into this:

function makeAdder() {
  var amount = 2;
  return function(number) {
    return number + amount;
  }
}
```

You can kinda see where this is going - because `amount = 2`, the inner function evaluates to:

```
return function(number) {
  return number + 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tell me if I understand this correctly:

The execution of the code starts at the line:

```
var addTwo = makeAdder(2);
```

at this point makeAdder() is executed with the argument of 2 assigned to the param/variable 'amount'. The control then proceeds into the body of the function 'makeAdder'[as it was invoked], but then it suddenly returns not a value, but a whole function definition ('function(number){..}'). At this point makeAdder(amount) virtually becomes function(number) {...} since what is returned is just a function definition and not an execution of it, this is then passed to addTwo via the var definition. At this point addTwo becomes a "virtual" function(number) {..}, then control sees an execution of addTwo (now a "virtual" function(number)) with an assigned argument of 3, which then passes into the number variable inside the "virtual" 'function()'. And the addition can now proceed inside the function body { return number+amount;} with the sum of 5 being produced.

What I really think is amazing and funny here (if what I understood is correct) is that the variable 'amount' is lucky because its value is not obliterated when the body returned the definition of function(number){..} to makeAdder(amount). As if he went into a variable 'limbo', and came back to code world when the function(number){..} called it. What I learned here is that control reads the code in a linear way (not completely and instantaneously) across the different pathways inside the code like a train in a track, and some variables can, by chance or whatever you call it, save itself from being "over-run". Is this how other programming languages work or is this unique to javascript?

Sorry for my non-programmer way of explaining it, as it is easier for me to understand it this way.

Comment: I hope you know the concept of class, objects and member variables. When  you call the outer function, that literally behaves like creating an object of makeAdder. I am calling it a class because classes are created in javascript through function keywords, IIFE and more. When you create an object of makeAdder class, you assigned a member variable a value of 2. Since this variable remains inside object of class, and returns the function inside the scope of object of makeAdder, it is available to returned function. When you evaluate the returned function, value of the member variable........

Comment: ......is available to the inner function. When inner function is evaluated, it takes value of member variable amount from the object of the class, and number from the parameter passed into it. Sums it up and returns result.  https://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/

Comment: I have updated my answer above to answer your doubts you have raised in your answer here, and it is a long answer. Take some time to go through it. It will make these things very clear.